# Assign only certain words from a list to a variable

Tags: python, list

I am trying to assign the words from the list `cards` that are in the list `playerdeck` to a variable. This is the code I tried to use but it returns `False`.

```
playerdeck = ['Five of Spades', 'Eight of Spades',
              'Eight of Clubs', 'Four of Clubs', 'Ace of Spades',
              'Eight of Hearts', 'Four of Diamonds'] 

cards = ['King', 'Queen', 'Jack', 'Ace',
     'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five',
     'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine',
     'Ten']

new = cards in playerdeck
print(new)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: of course, but in the actual code I have, playerdeck is a list of 7 random objects from another list. In the op, I just simplified it is all.

Comment: have a look at the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
>>> playerdeck = ['Five of Spades', 'Eight of Spades',
              'Eight of Clubs', 'Four of Clubs', 'Ace of Spades',
              'Eight of Hearts', 'Four of Diamonds']
>>> cards = ['King', 'Queen', 'Jack', 'Ace',
     'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five',
     'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine',
     'Ten']
>>> 
>>> for pd in playerdeck:
    temp = pd.split(" ")
    for data in temp:
        if data in cards:
            print data


Five
Eight
Eight
Four
Ace
Eight
Four
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Card:
   def __init__(self,value):
       self.value = value
   def __eq__(self,other):          
       return str(other) in self.value
   def __str__(self):
       return self.value
   def __repr__(self):
       return "<Card:'%s'>"%self
   def __hash__(self):
       return hash(self.value.split()[0])

playerdeck = map(Card,['Five of Spades', 'Eight of Spades',
              'Eight of Clubs', 'Four of Clubs', 'Ace of Spades',
              'Eight of Hearts', 'Four of Diamonds'] )

cards = set(['King', 'Queen', 'Jack', 'Ace',
     'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five',
     'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine',
     'Ten'])

print cards.intersection(playerdeck)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it first iterates through the cards and checks which of them is in the player_deck. If there is a match, it appends it to new and goes to the next card.

```
new = []

for card in cards:
    for deck in player_deck:
        if card.lower() in deck.lower():
            new.append(card)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the small solution using two loops and single conditional statement(*just 3 lines*):

```
>>> playerdeck = ['Five of Spades', 'Eight of Spades',
...               'Eight of Clubs', 'Four of Clubs', 'Ace of Spades',
...               'Eight of Hearts', 'Four of Diamonds']
>>> cards = ['King', 'Queen', 'Jack', 'Ace',
...      'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five',
...      'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine',
...      'Ten']
>>> for pd in playerdeck:
...     for card in cards:
...             if card in pd:
...                     print card
... 
Five
Eight
Eight
Four
Ace
Eight
Four
```

---

Or if you want to try with **list comprehension:**

```
>>> playerdeck = ['Five of Spades', 'Eight of Spades',
...               'Eight of Clubs', 'Four of Clubs', 'Ace of Spades',
...               'Eight of Hearts', 'Four of Diamonds']
>>> cards = ['King', 'Queen', 'Jack', 'Ace',
...      'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five',
...      'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine',
...      'Ten']
>>> result = [card for pd in playerdeck for card in cards if card in pd]
>>> result
['Five', 'Eight', 'Eight', 'Four', 'Ace', 'Eight', 'Four']
```